# In-built key Generation Algorithm using SHA256

Tags: sha256, encryption-symmetric, data-security

I am working on an application in c# .Net where data needs to be encrypted and Since data privacy is my ultimate motive , I am doing it using AES Encryption and I use PasswordDervieBytes for determining the Secret Key. Now Since it uses SHA1 which is broken , I would like to know whether there is an in-built function which uses SHA256 for obtaining my secret key. I also know that RFC2898 can be used but then it also uses SHA1... So, Is there an In-built function which uses SHA256 algorithm ? Thank You in advance for your valuable answers !!

Comment: SHA is not an encryption algorithm. It's a hashing algorithm (the clue is in the name!). The two are quite different (encryption is reversible, hashing is not).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SHA256Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed.aspx) class that will **hash** the input. It will not encrypt it...